# how to show different messages to different user types in grails/java

Tags: java, grails

I'm writing a series of webpage wizards for an application process.  A wizard is 30 pages long.  There are 4 different types of users.  Depending on the type of user, they may see different static text in each page of the form, or they may see different fields on the form.  That's 4 user types X 30 pages = 120 total webpages.  85% of the 4 wizards UI are the same.  The differences vary from page to page and from user type to user type, so it isn't like I can have 25 common wizard pages, and 5 unique to each user type.

I'm trying to write the code so that I don't have 30 pages duplicated 4 times.  I'm using grails templates so that I have just 30 pages that pull in the differences based on the user type.  One idea I had was piggy-backing on the internationalization built into grails.  For example if I have a user with a role of Role_Finance, their wizard would pull the text to display from messages.properties.  If I have a user with a role of Role_Contractor, I could assign them a different locale (spanish) so the wizard pulled different text from messages_es.properties.

While I realize this is not the intent of the grails internationalization, it seems like this would be a clean solution.  This isn't an international application so I'm not concerned about losing that functionality.  Anybody had to do something like this before and find a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Like doelleri said you can build your message keys in a flexible way.

If the message depends on the user role you can extend the message key by the name of the role. For example you can define message keys like this:

```
step1.welcome.Role_Finance=Hello Finance
step1.welcome.Role_Contractor=Hello Contractor
```

and resolve them dependent on the user role

```
<g:message code="step1.welcome.${ user.getRole() }" />
```

If you have a lot of messages like this you can also think about creating a special message tag which adds the role automatically.

Comment: This sounded good until I started implementing it.  Then I realized in springsecurity the User object has a Set of Roles.  I could check the first role, but if I add more roles later on to the user object it could cause problems.

Comment: THan add another method to the user class which returns the "type" of the user. You can check roles or anything else within this method. Or think about your design, maybe spring security roles aren't the best way to differentiate users.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use a different locale in an abuse of i18n, instead add the user's role into the message key like `wizard1.Role_Finance.field1=...`.